# Display success message

Tags: node.js, angular, html, express

I have a  form , I want to display a success message after a user click submit

here is what i have.

```
 <form [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4">Comment author</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" formControlName="author" #author />
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['author'].invalid && (angForm.controls['author'].dirty || angForm.controls['author'].touched)"
              class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['author'].errors.required">
                Name is required.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4">comment description</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="description" #description/>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['description'].invalid && (angForm.controls['description'].dirty || angForm.controls['description'].touched)"
              class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['description'].errors.required">
                description is required.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button (click)="addReview(author.value, description.value)" [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

here is component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MoviesService } from '../movies.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie',
  templateUrl: './movie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie.component.scss']
})
export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {
  movie: object;
  review: {};
  addreview: {};
  addreviews: any[];
  angForm: FormGroup;
  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  constructor(private _flashMessagesService: FlashMessagesService, private fb: FormBuilder, private route: Router, private http: HttpClient, private activeRouter: ActivatedRoute, private moviesService: MoviesService) {
    this.movie = [];
    this.review = [];
    this.addreviews = [];
    this.createForm();
  }
  createForm() {
    this.angForm = this.fb.group({
      author: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  addReview(author, description) {
    this.moviesService.addReview(author, description);
    this._flashMessagesService.show('Your comment was successfully added');
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

when a user click submit button everything works fine, data are submitted and saved to database but no flash message is displayed eg Your comment was successfully added' what do I need to change to display success message?

Comment: You could perhaps add bootstrap alerts to display feedback messages to the user.

Comment: @bradmcallister hii can you please show me example ? am new to this stuff

Comment: @bradmcallister where do I need to add that alert?

Comment: The documentation for alerts can be found here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/alert/examples. And you would want to set the alert to appear where you have the flashMessagesService.

Comment: I know about that my problem. is I dont know how proper to implement it, u can see it :( can you please provide some similar example ?

Comment: did you import the flash messages module in your module.ts? can you post the module.ts code

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I guess you missed including a container for the flash messages to display in your html.
 Add this in your html wherever you want to show the flash message.

```
    <flash-messages></flash-messages>
```

Comment: I have that in app component :)  `addReview(author, description) {
    this.moviesService.addReview(author, description);
    this._flashMessagesService.show('Your comment was successfully added');
  } something is wrong here` and in html something is wrong can you give a working example? @yer

Answer (score 0):

Did you seen any error in console in browser window.

Make sure you have to added `FlashMessagesModule` in app.module.ts file

```
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

@NgModule({
    imports: [        
        FlashMessagesModule.forRoot(),
    ]
})
```

Add this tag in your app component file

```
<flash-messages></flash-messages>
```

For more details visit official site.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-flash-messages

I hope its helpful.